# if statement not working properly?

Tags: c

When i run the program, if i enter 0 for the "d" option, it doesn't print what i set the if statement to print when a 0 is entered as u can see almost at the end of the program. The comments in this program are part of the program i just made it like this so you can see the code that is not in comment form is my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    // David Brand
    int result, num, num1, calc, calc1, mark;
    char A1, A2, ch;
    float num2, num3, result1;

    printf("\n\n\tMenu");
    printf("\n\n\ta. Addition");
    printf("\n\tb. Subtraction");
    printf("\n\tc. Multiplication");
    printf("\n\td. Division");
    printf("\n\n\tSelect a, b, c or d: ");
    ch = getch();
    if (ch == 'a')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("\n\n\tPlease add the two numbers ");
        scanf("%d", &result);
        if (result == num + num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        if (result != num + num1)
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    if (ch == 'b')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("\n\n\tPlease subtract from the first number ");
        scanf("%d", &result);
        if (result == num - num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        if (result != num - num1)
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    if (ch == 'c')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("\n\n\tPlease multiply the two ");
        scanf("%d", &result);
        if (result == num * num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        if (result != num * num1)
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    if (ch == 'd')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
        scanf("%f", &num2);
        if (num2 != 0)
            printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
        scanf("%f", &num3);
        printf("\n\n\tPlease divide the two numbers ");
        scanf("%f", &result1);
        if (num2 == 0)
            printf("\n\n\tZero divisor");
        printf("\n\tHit a key to end the program");
        getch();
        system("cls");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (result1 == num2 / num3)
        printf("\n\n\tCorrect");

    if (result1 != num2 / num3)
        printf("\n\n\tWrong");

    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Format The Code Please. And show only the relevant snippet.

Comment: Did you enter 0 for `num2` or `num3`?

Comment: Looks like you're missing some brackets.

Comment: @AntonH i did enter 0 for num2 and it doesnt work.

Comment: `man indent`. It's your friend.

Comment: You say an `if` statement is not working properly, mind telling us *which* one it is? Also, please provide actual and expected output for some (specified) input.

Comment: Just for the sake of code readability, you should look into using switch statements instead of chaining if statements. I believe that it also has a slight compiler optimization if you use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
if(ch=='d')
{
   printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
   scanf("%f", &num2);
   if(num2==0)
   {
      printf("\n\n\tZero divisor");
      printf("\n\tHit a key to end the program");
      getch();
      system("cls");
      exit(0);    
   }
   else if(num2!=0)
   {
      printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
      scanf("%f", &num3);
      printf("\n\n\tPlease divide the two numbers ");
      scanf("%f", &result1);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks i already made it work!

Comment: Thanks, Will appreciate if you accept my answer so the question is closed

Answer (score 0):

Here is that section of code after running through auto-layout:

```
if(ch=='d')
{
    printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    if(num2!=0)
        printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
    scanf("%f", &num3);
    printf("\n\n\tPlease divide the two numbers ");
    scanf("%f", &result1);
    if(num2==0)
        printf("\n\n\tZero divisor");
    printf("\n\tHit a key to end the program");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    exit(0);
}
```

It doesn't print anything after you enter `0` because it falls straight through to another `scanf`.  If you want more than one statement to be conditionally executed with `if`, you need to enclose those statements in curly brackets.

I expect you wanted something like this:

```
if(ch=='d')
{
    printf("\n\n\tEnter a number ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    if(num2!=0) {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter another number ");
        scanf("%f", &num3);

        printf("\n\n\tPlease divide the two numbers ");
        scanf("%f", &result1);
    } else {
        printf("\n\n\tZero divisor");
        printf("\n\tHit a key to end the program");
        getch();
        system("cls");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: He is not ending program here, He is calculating result1 afterwards.. There are so many errors

Comment: I think there are other errors too.  The OP wants to detect the zero divisor, but it should be `num3`, not `num2`.  I'm sure that this is enough to go on for now.

Comment: thank you @paddy i just seen that .. my mistake.. too much programming my brain is fried lol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a c compiler at work but I think this should fix most of the issues your having

Also don't you need to check for num3 to be 0 not num2? 0 / 5 is fine 5 / 0 is not

You don't need to check for == and then immediately check for != you know from the == that the opposite of that using else is !=

You should be able to input the two numbers or even the answer as well into a single line to make it easier on the user using a single scanf line also you could make part of this into functions as there is alot of repeated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    //David Brand
    int result,num,num1,calc,calc1,mark;
    char A1,A2,ch;
    float num2,num3,result1;

    printf("\n\n\tMenu");
    printf("\n\n\ta. Addition");
    printf("\n\tb. Subtraction");
    printf("\n\tc. Multiplication");
    printf("\n\td. Division");
    printf("\n\n\tSelect a, b, c or d: ");
    ch=getch();

    if(ch=='a')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter two numbers separated by a space i.e. 5 7");
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &num1);

        printf("\n\n\tPlease add the two numbers ");
        scanf("%d", &result);

        if (result == num + num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        else
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    else if(ch=='b')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter two numbers separated by a space i.e. 5 7");
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &num1);

        printf("\n\n\tPlease subtract from the first number ");
        scanf("%d", &result);

        if(result == num-num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        else
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    else if(ch=='c')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter two numbers separated by a space i.e. 5 7");
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &num1);

        printf("\n\n\tPlease multiply the two ");
        scanf("%d", &result);

        if(result == num * num1)
            printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
        else
            printf("\n\n\tWrong");
    }
    else if(ch=='d')
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEnter two numbers separated by a space i.e. 5.7 7.5");
        scanf("%f %f", &num2, &num3);

        if(num3 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\n\tZero divisor");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n\tPlease divide the two numbers ");
            scanf("%f", &result1);

            if(result1 == (num2 / num3))
                printf("\n\n\tCorrect");
            else
                printf("\n\n\tWrong");
        }           
    }   
    printf("\n\tHit a key to end the program");
    getch();
    exit(0);
}
```